# How to create search box in navigation layer?

Tags: magento-1.9

How to implement search box in navigation layer ? Please suggest me some idea for this?

[image]

My Layer navigation code

```
<dl id="narrow-by-list">
                <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
                <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
                <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
  </dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create it yourself, for example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5vs80Lso/)

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="brand-search">
<ul class="brands">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="value">Intel</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="value">AMD</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="value">Cooler Master</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('#brand-search').on('keyup',function(){
    var term = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('ul.brands li').each(function(){
        if( $(this).find('span.value').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term) >= 0 ){
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please check my updated question

Comment: I saw your updated question, but what do you want with it? Be creative and implement a variation of my code?

Comment: i tried but it's not working

Comment: A little more information would be helpful, what did you try?

Comment: i tried your code but it showing my site url in that text box